# Random keeps spitting out same number

Tags: java

I'm currently tying to make a simple 2D world generator for a small game that I'm working on. The problem is the values I get from the random are all the same. Also, I don't want the generator creating blocks that are two blocks high, because then the player could not get through. Here's my code:

```
private void generateWorld() {
    Random r = new Random(Sys.getTime() / System.currentTimeMillis() * System.nanoTime());
    int bh = r. nextInt(1) + 1;
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x+=32) {

        theWorld.addBlock(new Block(BlockType.Grass, x, bh * 32));
        //r = new Random(Sys.getTime() / System.currentTimeMillis() * System.nanoTime());
        bh = r.nextInt(1) + 1;
        System.out.println(bh);
    }
}
```

EDIT: `r.nextInt(2);` also creates a flat strip of land.
EDIT2: Fixed it, I was stupid and was only changing the r.nextInt() before the for loop. Forgot about the one inside it!

Comment: Doesn't `r.nextInt(1)` return `0` every time?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for nextInt?

Comment: More generally, r.nextInt(n) returns an int that is at least 0 and less than n. There is only one int that is at least 0 and less than 1. Perhaps you should be using r.nextInt(2).

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I changed it to `r.nextInt(2)`, still creates a flat strip of land.

Answer (score 1):

`r.nextInt(1)` would return always `0`. As a rule of thumb, `r.nextInt(x)` returns an integer within the range `0 to x-1`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as @Blender pointed out, is that nextInt(1) will return a value in the range [0, 1), which will always be 0.

Increase the value of `n` you pass in to create larger blocks.

Answer (score 0):

`nextInt(x)` returns a random integer between 0 and `x-1` inclusive. So `nextInt(1)` returns an integer between 0 and... 0.

Try `nextInt(2)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

nextInt(1) - will always return 0, the reason is that the parameter is the upperbound for random selection. try highering the parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

`nextInt(maxInt)` returns an int from `0` to `maxInt - 1`.
Replace `nextInt(1)` with something like `nextint(100)`

Comment: Then again, the player would not be able to pass through.

Comment: @JustinP: Pass through what? Why would the player be able to pass through blocks?